Protect matte black paint on door
I have indoor french door installed and painted with shellac based primer 2 coats and water based matte black paint with three coats. When I lightly rubbed the door with finger it makes scuffed marks. I have seen clear top coat varnish in matt in paint shop which is Cabot's Matt Water Based Cabothane Clear Interior Varnish. Is this good for preserving black matte without making it glossy?
